# Assembly Not Referenced compilation error in foreach loop in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, collections, iis-express

EDIT: I have checked and attempted a lot of the other Assembly Not Referenced issues found on SE, but I haven't found many dealing with what should be a built-in assembly (`System.Collections.Generic.List<t>`). This makes it difficult to manually add or remove the reference etc.

I am trying to build a PartialView from an API response. I have confirmed the response is correct and well-formed, my objects are being built correctly, but when I generate the Partial View, a Compilation Error is instead shown.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Here is the Razor view:

```
@using OpsComponent
@model OpsComponent.ComponentData

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach (Data metric in Model.Metrics)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="badge">@metric.Value</span>
                    @metric.Key<br/>
                </li>
            }

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Data class definition:

```
public class Data
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }

    }
```

Where Status is an enum. I have checked in Debugging that the Model object is correct and well-formed before it is passed to the PartialView, but instead of a correct layout, I get the Server Error screen and a 500 response.

at the line `@foreach (Data metric in Model.Metrics)`

Action code for completeness:

```
public ActionResult ComponentDetail(string id)
        {
            var data = Client.GetComponentData(id.DecodeBase64ToString());
            var partialViewResult = PartialView("_ComponentDetail", data);
            return partialViewResult;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced, how to find the cause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I've added an edit explaining, but I think the challenge here compared to the many other "Not Referenced" SE questions is that they have been primarily dealing with either a) ReSharper "cannot resolve symbol" errors (not using R#), or b) user libraries, as opposed to built-in types list List<T>

Comment: Did you try to add `@using System.Collections.Generic`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have figured it out, and it was devilishly simple. I still don't know why this is necessary, but adding a new `assembly` tag to `web.config` seems to have resolved this issue. The tag I added was under the `<compilation>` tag and as follows:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</assemblies>
```

Simple, but has resolved the error and the view now renders correctly.

Comment: Work for me. Thx !

Comment: Notice that you need to surround the `<assemblies>` annotation with `<compilation>`.
Like this:
`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</assemblies>
`</compilation>`

Comment: `<add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>`
in my case

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently which is best described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0012

The problem was comming from two different references in PartialView.cshtml and MainView.cshtml, each referring to two different classes in Razor pages; Intersection was a foreach loop in the both views.

Solution was to add one more line:

```
<add assembly="NameOfTheProject.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

to the already existing assembly info in Web.config under Views folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how references are added in the Razor Engine.
This issue is reported https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/415.